# Error when adding a column with several options

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-activerecord

I have the following migration in the system I'm working on:

```
class CreateEstoqueGruposProdutos < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :est_grupos_produtos do |t|
      t.integer :grupos_produtos_nivel_id, :null => false, foreign_key: { references: :est_grupos_produtos_niveis, on_update: :cascade, on_delete: :restrict }, index: { with: [:id], unique: true, :name => 'unique_grupos_produtos_id_nivel' }

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

It basically creates a table with an integer column that references (foreign_key) another table and add some options to the index.

Now, I need to do the same thing with a table that already exists. I need to add a column like this to a table with existing data.

I'm trying to do:

```
class ChangeCadastrosPerfilNiveis < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :cad_perfil_niveis, :perfil_niveis_nivel_id, :integer, :null => false, :default => 1, foreign_key: { references: :cad_perfil_niveis_niveis, on_update: :cascade, on_delete: :restrict }, index: { with: [:id], unique: true, :name => 'unique_perfil_niveis_id_nivel' }
  end
end
```

It's not working. The error output is:

```
-- add_column(:cad_perfil_niveis, :perfil_niveis_nivel_id, :integer, {:null=>false, :default=>1, :foreign_key=>{:references=>:cad_perfil_niveis_niveis, :on_update=>:cascade, :on_delete=>:restrict}, :index=>{:with=>[:id], :unique=>true, :name=>"unique_perfil_niveis_id_nivel"}})
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

wrong number of arguments (5 for 3)
```

Backtrace:

```
    wrong number of arguments (5 for 3)
/home/sinetic/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/foreigner-1.1.6/lib/foreigner/connection_adapters/sql2003.rb:17:in `add_foreign_key'
/home/sinetic/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/schema_plus-1.1.2/lib/schema_plus/active_record/column_options_handler.rb:24:in `schema_plus_handle_column_options'
/home/sinetic/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/schema_plus-1.1.2/lib/schema_plus/active_record/foreign_keys.rb:125:in `add_column'
/home/sinetic/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:450:in `block in method_missing'
/home/sinetic/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:424:in `block in say_with_time'
/home/sinetic/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p547/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:280:in `measure'
/home/sinetic/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:424:in `say_with_time'
/home/sinetic/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:444:in `method_missing'
/home/sinetic/www/next/cadastros/db/migrate/20150223112512_change_cadastros_perfil_niveis.rb:4:in `change'
/home/sinetic/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:393:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/home/sinetic/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p547/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:280:in `measure'
/home/sinetic/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:393:in `block in migrate'
/home/sinetic/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:118:in `with_connection'
/home/sinetic/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:377:in `migrate'
/home/sinetic/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:512:in `migrate'
/home/sinetic/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:704:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/home/sinetic/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:759:in `call'
/home/sinetic/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:759:in `block in ddl_transaction'
/home/sinetic/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:192:in `transaction'
/home/sinetic/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
/home/sinetic/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:759:in `ddl_transaction'
/home/sinetic/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:703:in `block in migrate'
/home/sinetic/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:684:in `each'
/home/sinetic/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:684:in `migrate'
/home/sinetic/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:554:in `up'
/home/sinetic/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:535:in `migrate'
/home/sinetic/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:153:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/sinetic/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p547/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
/home/sinetic/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p547/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in execute'
/home/sinetic/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p547/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
/home/sinetic/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p547/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
/home/sinetic/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p547/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:158:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/sinetic/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p547/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/sinetic/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p547/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/sinetic/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p547/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
/home/sinetic/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p547/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:116:in `invoke_task'
/home/sinetic/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p547/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:94:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/home/sinetic/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p547/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:94:in `each'
/home/sinetic/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p547/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in top_level'
/home/sinetic/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p547/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/sinetic/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p547/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:88:in `top_level'
/home/sinetic/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p547/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:66:in `block in run'
/home/sinetic/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p547/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/sinetic/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p547/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
/home/sinetic/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:32:in `<top (required)>'
/home/sinetic/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/home/sinetic/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
/home/sinetic/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/home/sinetic/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

How do this options could be added to the table in question without dropping it and creating it again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `change_table` method:

```
change_table(:cad_perfil_niveis) do |t|
  t.integer :perfil_niveis_nivel_id, :null => false, :default => 1, foreign_key: { references: :cad_perfil_niveis_niveis, on_update: :cascade, on_delete: :restrict }, index: { with: [:id], unique: true, :name => 'unique_perfil_niveis_id_nivel' }
end
```

Comment: Could you please provide full backtrace?

Comment: I've edited the original post with the full error of the original code. But, the error with the code you suggested is exactly the same (with the new code in the error, of course)

Comment: It doesn't have backtrace. Try to run `rake --trace db:migrate`. It should generate backtrace.

Comment: Seems like your problem related to [foreigner](https://rubygems.org/gems/foreigner). Try to update it to latest version.

Comment: Or it can be related to [schema_plus](https://rubygems.org/gems/schema_plus) gem because it call `add_foreign_key` method of `foreigner`. Try to update it too.

Comment: I is related to foreigner as you said! Actually, I can't update the gem because the project is too big and it may cause some unwanted behavior. But I split the code in two. The first added the column and the second added the foreign key. I worked like a charm! Thank you very much for your help. I will accept as answer, but I ask you to edit your post with this gem issue, to be a completed answer. Regards!

Comment: Excellent! :) Better to add solution to your post.